# Setting position defaults for an app on the first run

Tags: objective-c, ios, installation, position, default

I have a drumming app that has user-moveable drums onscreen. The user is able to customize the position, size, volume, and sound that defines each of the drums. It currently functions very nicely, and you can make some pretty awe inspiring drum kits with it.

When you first open the app however, it doesn't look very appealing. This is because I had to initialize the drums with code and guess at their positions. The current default position of the drums for a user starting the app for the first time looks like someone's closet, with drums all over the place and no apparent order.

Does anyone have any ideas as to how I can programmatically position drums into a nice drum set? I can make some good ones by dragging them around in the app, but I can't get the app to start with one of them.

Can I access their positions with the debugger and write them down somehow? Copy the drum kit from user defaults?

All help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add `NSLog` statements printing out the actual position of the drums and put them into an plist to load from when the app starts.

Comment: I ended up logging the drum name and position, so this is exactly right.